# Error: Invalid provider registry host in terraform on windows 10

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider

i`m using terraform in windows 10
terraform version : 1.4.5
provider: local

Initializing provider plugins...

- Finding latest version of hashicorp/local...
  2023-04-17T08:44:44.279+0330 [DEBUG] Service discovery for registry.terraform.io at https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json
  2023-04-17T08:44:44.279+0330 [TRACE] HTTP client GET request to https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json
  ╷
  │ Error: Invalid provider registry host
  │
  │ The host "registry.terraform.io" given in in provider source address "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local" does not offer a Terraform provider
  │ registry.

How can I resolve this?